# How to bleed clutch for Ford Econovan 1989

Tags: ford, clutch

How do I bleed a clutch for a Ford Econovan 1989 model after putting in new master cylinder kit? as in where is the bleed nipple? It sure isn't the one on the steering column, it only works for brake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a bleed nipple down by the slave cylinder.

Like [this](http://youtu.be/c-m5F0zEvyo?t=18m)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this model uses a hydraulic throwout bearing to disengage the clutch. Some brands come pre-bled with a clutch mastercylinder,hose and slave as one assembly. Look for some type of cover on the bell housing that will allow access to the throwout bearing. You may be able to follow the hydraulic line to the tranny to get an idea where to look. You may be lucky and find a bleeder nipple you can reach. If there is no access then the transmission must be removed to repair or replace the throwout bearing.